# Pagination Next/Previous not working intermittently on iPhone

Tags: magento2, ultimo

I believe this is a Ultimo theme issue. The author has stopped updating the theme. I have this theme on Magento 2.3.3. Pagination Next/Previous not working intermittently on iPhone. Sometimes it works after clicking twice with no response or error in console to one click. As you can see from the screenshot taken from a iPhone that a click on page 2 is stuck with number 2 label highlighted with black color.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

*the example from OP's question: http://ultimo.infortis-themes.com/demo/default/fashion.html*

EDIT: Did a little digging and got some more info that I guess made my last answer kind of pointless so here you go

Looks like Apple have been known to cause a similar issue when things are changed/shown during `:hover` on an anchor tag. It's their attempt at being too smart for their own good by the looks of it. First click causes the hover effect, second click causes the actual click.

Kinda sucks that this is a part of Apple's "intended functionality" but there's possibly ways around it. You can try wrap the `:hover` CSS in a media query to not change colour on touch devices, and there's some other little tricks I found here: https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/

Comment: You need to go previous/next scroll down and keep doing previous/next page. Remember you need to scroll down and use the bottom previous/next page 1 and 2. And make sure it is iOS 13 plus.

Comment: here is the video. https://youtu.be/_GabXBEPl2I

Comment: Edited the answer entirely for you. that css-tricks link might help

Comment: Could you please provide exact file location and code changes?

Comment: Can't help with exactly where without purchasing myself, however you can try look for the selector `.pager .pages li a:hover` in your files, that's the CSS selector causing the colour change. As for what exact changes, I can't say for sure, but that css-tricks.com article has some ideas on what you can try out.